# Cordova Mobilefirst Android platform not able to export sign in APK binary file

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Mobilefirst platform 8.0 based on Cordova application and i have export signed APK file but i could not able generate.
I tried android studio as well as command prompt / terminal, please find below the error logs i got it from android studio gradle build and command prompt also.

operating system : MAC os
android studio : 2.3+
cordova : 6.5.0
Mobilefirst 8.0

```
Error: /Users/user1/Documents/Testapp/Push/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: there were 7 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced method 'long getContentLengthLong()' in library class java.net.HttpURLConnection
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced method 'long getHeaderFieldLong(java.lang.String,long)' in library class java.net.HttpURLConnection
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: there were 6 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*** What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details**

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: Can you provide the contents of your build.gradle

Comment: buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }

Comment: signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is a misconfigured Proguard rules file. Follow the blog [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/09/19/mfp-80-obfuscating-android-code-with-proguard/), to successfully obfuscate your Android project.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in your profuard-mfp.txt file :-

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.**
```